# Most efficient way to maintain list of error codes in Java

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns, error-handling

I am working on a new project that has about 100 error codes and corresponding messages.
The way it was done before is to use a constants class with all these codes and messages as final Strings.

Personally, I don't like the idea as addition/removal of error codes requires a code change.
Other option I have is to create a cache(HashMap) of these error codes loaded from a properties file or from a database.

What is the most efficient way to maintain a list of error codes ?

Comment: How do you measure efficiency? If those errors are referenced in the code, the major benefit of defining them as constants/enums are the compile time check. If you just want a simple way to map objects to errors, perhaps you could have Spring injecting error code and message to those objects.

Comment: I second the need for clarity on "efficient" :). In terms of speed, the list of constants will be the fastest, since the right string is "found" at compile time. If you want to make the list dynamic/configurable without recompilation, you can gain some speed by storing the strings in an array with the error code being the index (assuming your error codes are not huge integers, you will waste some memory and gains some lookup speed :)

Comment: I took efficient to mean maintaining code (second paragraph and use of maintain in third paragraph). This isn't a question about CPU efficiency.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/209693/best-practices-to-create-error-codes-pattern-for-an-enterprise-project-in-c ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, by efficiency I meant more maintainable in the future and with that in mind , I would like to know which method would have the least performance hit in the long run.

Comment: Fuhrmanator ..thanks for the link but I did check it out before posting the question. The link is more like best practices for error handling but does not detail how to manage the error codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 100 error codes I think it is easier to go with the properties file, and use a Properties object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

You can do it with a database too, but assuming you use JDBC you have to connect/select data/process result set/close resources, so it is a little more complicated.